# Using MediaElement.JS in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, mediaelement.js

So I have what I think for most of you, is a stupid question, but I can not figure this out by myself. I'm building a WordPress theme for a friend of mine, and I need to build a custom looking audio player. I think, that MediaElementJS is a good place to start.

In my understanding, MediaElementJS is part of the core features of WordPress, and I have added it in my functions.php with the code

```
    function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

But still, the normal browser player is showing in all the browsers. I have read a lot of topics here on StackOverflow and over the internet, but I just can't figure out where it goes wrong. Since it's part of the WordPress core I don't need to install the plugin that is also available right? Also I tried installing it, but it then also shows it as the basic browser player.

Is their someone here, that can teach me how I implement MediaElementJS properly in my theme? I think I can figure out the styling part out, but the installing of the MEJS, I don't know where to begin nor look for good instructions that are really going to help. It seems inpossible to find a good tutorial on this :(

I really hope someone can help me out with this.
Thanks in advance!

(since I'm working locally I don't have my site running somewhere, if
needed, I can host it somewhere!)

Comment: I would first look at the dev console (F12) to see if there are any errors i.e. script files not loaded. Then checkout on how to implement the library on your web page (https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/usage.md)

Comment: @jeff I don't get any errors in the console. Thanks for the link, should I use the JQuery and implement this in the header.php? Or should I use it somewhere else? Tips and tricks are more then welcome :)